# SSH login through the VMware Workstation NAT is closed immediately

Tags: centos, ssh, nat, vmware-workstation

I have three VMs that are setup with the VMware Workstation:

- VM1 (CentOS 6, 192.168.230.128)
- VM2 (CentOS 7, 192.168.230.129)
- VM3 (CentOS 8, 192.168.230.130)

Host machine has public IP 192.168.100.1. NAT is configured to forward ports:

- 2221 -> 192.168.230.128:22
- 2222 -> 192.168.230.129:22
- 2223 -> 192.168.230.130:22

External client logs in as:

- `ssh -p 2221 user@192.168.100.1`
- `ssh -p 2222 user@192.168.100.1`
- `ssh -p 2223 user@192.168.100.1`

All logins work within the host machine (e.g. `ssh user@192.168.230.130` to login in the VM3). The problem is that login from external client to the VM3 (CentOS 8) is closed immediately after connection with server logs:

```
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user user
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Accepted password for user from IP port 22346 ssh2
```

`ssh -v` yields following results:

```
user@192.168.100.1's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.100.1 ([192.168.100.1]:2223).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.4.0beta8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.100.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.100.1 closed.
```

To summarize:

- All logins work from the host machine
- Logins to VM1 and VM2 work from external client
- Login to the VM3 from external client is immediately closed
- sshd_config is the same for all VMs (default files, no modifications)
- All required firewall ports are open

Why this happens only for the CentOS 8 machine when logging in through the NAT? Where’s the catch?

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: Logs from the server are in the question (3 lines).